# MySQL query output a value a hour (controlled by timestamp column)

Tags: php, mysql, database

A cronjob executes a script every 10 minutes, to capture the fan count of facebook
fanpages. E.g. 3 pages are under observation right now, than the
sum of data which is generated in a hour is 18 (6/hour/page).
The results are stored in a database (queryid, name, likes, timestamp)

Now I want to display a value e.g. each hour (each 30 minutes whatever) of a valuable (24 hours, 48 hours whatever) timerange, and not the complete values of a day (2592 vs. 72 rows)
How is this possible?

I hope you'll understand my problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL leys you `GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME( column ))`. Or by `DAY`, `HOUR` and even `DAYOFMONTH` . That should do give you some options too look at.

The full list would be [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You should be able to order by any function which returns a value.